# How to launch self-hosted WebListener web endpoint?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, self-hosting, asp.net-core-webapi

I have written an AspNetCore.Mvc, v. 1.1.0, application and am self-hosting it with the WebListener server. In keeping with the docs I've read, I am not using IIS-Integration.
It debugs nicely on my machine. When I publish it to my DEV server, I can run the console there and hit my endpoint across the network. I have correctly configured

My question is about the best practice for making this self-hosted WebListener application run as a Windows service that will start when the machine starts. Should I incorporate something like TopShelf to do that or is there something native to AspNetCore that I'm not aware of?

I have (or think I have) followed the instructions found on these two links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting

http://andrewlock.net/configuring-urls-with-kestrel-iis-and-iis-express-with-asp-net-core/

Comment: If IIS starts when the machine starts. Your app should too.

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect that I'm not using IIS here as, per my understanding, WebListener and IIS are not combined.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to configure your app to work with the hosting AspNetCore.

Add these to your dependencies in the `project.json`

```
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices": "1.0.0-*"
```

Here is an example of the StartUp Class, I never did a WebListener so this would need to be modified.

```
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(@"Path\To\Content\Root")
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

    ///input logic depending on the Environment variables.
    host.RunAsService();
```

That being said, I don't understand your aversion to IIS and Kestrel. You HAVE to be on a Windows machine in order to run as a service. Therefor IIS and Kestrel should be even more debug friendly that WebListener.